# How to count the number of values associated with a key

Tags: python, dictionary, find, key

Given the following dictionary, I want to find out which key had the most values. If I were to have a longer dictionary and wanted to know which key had the most values programmatically (without visual inspection), how would i go about doing that? The only way i can think of is as follows:

```
dic = {'attacks': ['kick','puch','slap','elbow'], \
  'defense': ['block','parry','dodge']}
```

dic = 
{'attacks': ['kick','puch','slap','elbow'], 'defense': ['block','parry','dodge']}

```
key_values_list = []
for key in dic:
    key_name = ''
    num = 0 
    for item in dic[key]:
        num +=1
    key_values_list.append((key,num))

for  k,v in key_values_list:
    print k,v
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code will count the instances of the key labeled attacks:

```
>>> max(((k, len(v)) for k, v in dic.items()), key=lambda x: x[1])
('attacks', 4)
>>>
```

Comment: Use a generator instead of a list comprehension by changing `[`,`]` to `(`,`)`

Comment: Instead of the `lambda` for the key, you could use `operator.itemgetter`, or you could just construct the tuple the other way around in the first place and rely on the natural sort order of tuples.

Answer (score 5):

```
>>> dic = {'attacks': ['kick','puch','slap','elbow'], 'defense': ['block','parry','dodge']}
>>> max(dic, key=lambda k: len(dic[k]))
'attacks'
```

Comment: I see this tells me which key has the most values but is there something i can use that will tell me how many values?

Comment: @Crispy: if you assign the result to a variable `maxkey`, `len(dic[maxkey])` will give you that.

Comment: @Crispy: alternatively, `max(len(v) for v in dic.itervalues())`.